# Apache console accesses network drives, service does not?

Tags: windows, apache

I have an apache 2.2 server running Django.  We have a network drive T: which we need constant access to within our Django app.  When running Apache as a service, we cannot access this drive, as far as any django code is concerned the drive does not exist.

If I add...

```
<Directory "t:/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       allow from all
</Directory>
```

to the httpd.conf file the service no longer runs, but I can start apache as a console and it works fine, Django can find the network drive and all is well.

Why is there a difference between the console and the service?  Should there be a difference?  I have the service using my own log on so in theory it should have the same access as I do.

I'm keen to keep it running as a service as it's far less obtrusive when I'm working on the server (unless there's a way to hide the console?).  Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run it as a service do you run it as a Local System account or as a User Account? It's selected in the Log On tab of the "properties" pop up from the services tool from the "Administrative Tools" item in the control panel. Also, my apache doesn't like drive letters, you have to give it UNC's (//server/share/). I have been getting lots of flaky network drive behavior from Apache on Windows, too.